# How to format a huge XML file in Eclipse or in any other platform efficiently

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, memory, formatting

I have an **XML file of size ~0.8MB and containing ~30000 lines**. I opened that file in Eclipse and then attempted to format the content. I tried this several times, but each time Eclipse started not to respond and after 1-2 minutes I forced it to shut down.

Are there any configurations or plugins to make the formatting of such huge XML files easier with efficient memory usage on Eclipse platform? If you know programs working independent of Eclipse to accomplish the same task, it would be also useful for me.

Comment: Pain in the butt, but I'm pretty sure you could also format it in sections if nothing else works. That, or write a quick formatter that will strip out all newlines/not needed spaces (outside of tags usually) and then just keep a tab level and put new lines where you need.

Answer (score 2):

For huge files, try command line tools. They often work much more efficient. In your case, try [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) with the option `--format` or [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php) with `fo` ([docs](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#d0e543)).

Alternatively, give Eclipse a lot of memory (1-1.5GB) and be more patient. The XML editor in Eclipse is pretty slow for huge documents.